# How to solve $\sqrt{49-x^2}-\sqrt{25-x^2}=3$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I recognize the two difference of squares: $49-x^2$ and $25-x^2$.

I squared the equation to get:
${49-x^2}-2(\sqrt{(49-x^2)(25-x^2)})+{25-x^2}=9$

However, I can't quite figure out how to remove the root in the middle. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *Hint*: Rearrange the terms and square again.

Comment: You could move the square root to the RHS and gather other terms to the LHS. Then taking square and the root is removed.

Comment: Bring everything else except the root to the R.H.S. and square the equation again. After this step there should be only expressions involving $x^4$ and $x^2$ and numbers which is a biquadratic equation. This type you can solve by setting $z=x^2$ and afterwords you need to check every single solution because to square is not a aquivalent reshape operation.

Comment: If you multiply by $\sqrt{49-x^2}+\sqrt{25-x^2}$ you get $\sqrt{49-x^2}+\sqrt{25-x^2}=\frac{49-25}{3}$. If you call $A=\sqrt{49-x^2}$ and $B=\sqrt{25-x^2}$, you just got a system of equations $A-B=3$, $A+B=\frac{49-25}{3}$. So, $A=\frac{3+\frac{49-25}{3}}{2}$, from where you get $x^2=49-\left(\frac{3+\frac{49-25}{3}}{2}\right)^2$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**. You may just write
$$
{49-x^2}+{25-x^2}-9=2\sqrt{(49-x^2)(25-x^2)}
$$ simplify and square both sides *once again*.

Comment: You need to show before that $\sqrt{49-x^2}-\sqrt{25-x^2}\geq0$ and $65-2x^2\geq0,$ otherwise your solution is total wrong.

Comment: Sure, needless to say.

Comment: Sure we need to say it. Your method does not help for the following equation $\sqrt{x+2}=x.$

Comment: Thank you for this precious explanation.

Comment: You are welcome! Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Another solution
\begin{align*}
\sqrt {49 - x^2} - \sqrt {25 - x^2} &= 3\\
\sqrt {49-x^2} &= 3+ \sqrt {25-x^2}\\
49-x^2 &= 25 -x^2 + 9 + 6\sqrt {25-x^2}\\
15 &= 6 \sqrt {25 - x^2}\\
25 - x^2 &= \frac {25} 4\\
x^2 &= \frac {75}4\\
x &= \pm \frac 5 2 \sqrt 3.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$\sqrt{49-x^2}-\sqrt{25-x^2}=3$$ and 
$$\left(\sqrt{49-x^2}-\sqrt{25-x^2}\right)\left(
\sqrt{49-x^2}+\sqrt{25-x^2}\right)=3\left(\sqrt{49-x^2}+\sqrt{25-x^2}\right),$$
which gives 
$$\sqrt{49-x^2}+\sqrt{25-x^2}=8$$ and from here
$$\sqrt{49-x^2}=5.5,$$ which gives the answer:
$$\left\{-\sqrt{18.75},\sqrt{18.75}\right\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

First express one root: $$\sqrt{49-x^2}=3+\sqrt{25-x^2}$$
Now square:

$$ 49-x^2=9+6\sqrt{25-x^2}+ 25-x^2\implies \boxed{5=2\sqrt{25-x^2}}$$

and square again...

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\sqrt{49-x^2}+\sqrt{25-x^2}=\frac{(49-x^2)-(25-x^2)}{\sqrt{49-x^2}-\sqrt{25-x^2}}=\frac{24}{3}=8\,.$$
Together with $\sqrt{49-x^2}-\sqrt{25-x^2}=3$, we conclude that
$$\sqrt{49-x^2}=\frac{3+8}{2}=\frac{11}{2}\,.$$

> Therefore, $x^2=\dfrac{75}{4}$, or $x=\pm\dfrac{5\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

**P.S.:**  Oopsie, nextpuzzle already made a comment, giving the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good start. Now rearrange the equation so that only the square root remains on the left hand side. 
Take square again. Then you obtain a bi-quadratic equations, or "fake quartic" equation. Introduce a new variable $y=x^2$, and then you have a quadratic equation in $y$ that you can solve easily.

Note that taking squares is not an equivalent transformation, so in the end, you have to check all the solutions. Some, or in fact, all of them can be extraneous.

Answer (score 0):

Set $\;\;t^2=25-x^2,\;$ the equation becomes $$\begin{align}\sqrt{24+t^2}-\sqrt{t^2}&=3\\ \sqrt{24+t^2}&=|t|+3\\24+t^2&=t^2+6|t|+9\\|t|&=\frac{5}{2}
\end{align}$$
Then $x^2=25-\frac{25}{4}=3\cdot \frac{25}{4},$ from where $x=\pm \frac{5}{2}\sqrt 3.$